# How to make cairo-dock icons not to hide

Tags: cairo

How to make my cairo-dock icons not to hide(**always shown**).
[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Right click on the dock itself and choose 'Cairo Dock'->'Configure'.
- Under 'Behaviour' choose 'Visibility'.

[image]

- You will find a 'visibility of the main Dock' section with a 'visibility' drop down - select 'Always on top'.

[image]

That way, your dock will always be on top of any window.

Answer (score 0):

Cairo Dock (Docky) is a great alternative to the Unity panel. Docky is highly customizable, and the possibilities are almost endless.

As to your question, there are tons of resources out there to show you how to do this and other cool things. Here are a few that I have encountered recently (I intentionally selected sites with a broader appeal to benefit other surfers):

1) First, a basic tutorial (GLX-DOCK is chockablock with tips and hints.Look around!)
http://glx-dock.org/ww_page.php?p=A%20complete%20tutorial%20on%20how%20to%20customize%20your%20dock&lang=en

2) This one steps you through some cool Ubuntu deskop facelifts with Docky:
http://mylinuxexplore.blogspot.co.il/2013/02/simple-steps-to-decorate-linux-desktop.html

3) Here's another sub-site of askubuntu, dedicated to hot Cairo Dock questions:
https://askubuntu.com/tags/cairo-dock/hot

Have a ball.